# Is it possible to throw DD-WRT on a F5D8235-4 v2?

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have a [F5D8235-4](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=F5D8235-4%20v2&oe=utf-8&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=16330696765759563451&sa=X&ei=eAiOTteKGOjm0QGl-NhN&ved=0CD0Q8wIwAw) v2 and I was looking to run IPv6 on it using DD-WRT, has anyone tried this?  I haven't been able to find it listed in the [router database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it works with brainslayer version of DD-WRT, which can be downloaded [HERE](ftp://dd-wrt.com/others/eko/BrainSlayer-V24-preSP2/2011/04-09-11-r16785/Belkin-F5D8235-4_v2/). Use the original to DD-WRT bin file

Comment: j0hnnyr0tten, your answer is interesting, as long as @music2myear is right on his answer: the router model number of the DD-WRT firmware to download must be the exact one for yours. Did you use any special method to discover this, something like any forum? Or you solved it just googling? You supply a link to some http://dd-wrt.com URL, but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

If that router is not listed as working with the DDWRT system, then it won't work.

Especially considering the closest router numbers (see image) are listed as "not possible" it is highly likely that something about this router's architecture makes it completely incompatible with the DDWRT software.

[image]